# Base class for 2 windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have 2 windows. One is a regular window, the other is a MetroWindow (MahApps.Metro library).

How can I make an abstract base class that both can subclass?
Since my MetroWindow already inherits from the MetroWindow class and you can't inherit from 2 base classes I don't really know how to handle this.

Comment: There is no way around this. It is a basic requirement of the language that you cannot inherit from more than one concrete type. If your window already inherits from something.. there's nothing you can do to tack on another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would work ( I don't know mahapps) but i think they have to different baseclasses.

What do you want to make with both windows?

Perhaps you can extract that and call it from / with each window

Answer (score 0):

You can't subclass from two types - maybe you should invert your problem and look at composing your form from user controls which (while they won't be able to share a common base type) will be able to share common code.

Edit: You can host WPF in winforms, and also the other way round, but no idea if this works in TIFKAM